# Resize window with smooth transition for different height sizes

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Some context:**

I'm working on a Chrome Extension where the user can launch it via default "popup.html", or if the user so desires this Extension can be detached from the top right corner and be used on a popup window via `window.open`

This question will also apply for situations where users create a Shortcut for the extension on Chrome via:
"..." > "More tools" > "Create Shortcut"

**Problem:**

So what I need is for those cases where users use the extension detached via `window.open` or through a shortcut, when navigating through different options, for the Height of the window to be resized smoothly.

I somewhat achieve this but the animation is clunky and also the final height is not always the same. Sometimes I need to click twice on the button to resize too because 1 click won't be enough. Another issue is there is also some twitching of the bottom text near the edge of the window when navigating.

**Here's what I got so far:**

(`strWdif` and `strHdif` are used to compensate for some issues with CSS setting proper sizes which I haven't figured out yet.)

```
const popup = window;

function resizeWindow(popup) {
  setTimeout(function () {
  var strW = getComputedStyle(window.document.querySelector(".body_zero")).getPropertyValue("width");
  var strW2 = strW.slice(0, -2);
  var strWdif = 32;
  var bodyTargetWidth = (parseFloat(strW2) + parseFloat(strWdif));
  var strH = getComputedStyle(window.document.querySelector(".body_zero")).getPropertyValue("height");
  var strH2 = strH.slice(0, -2);
  var strHdif = 54;
  var bodyTargetHeight = (parseFloat(parseInt(strH2)) + parseFloat(strHdif));
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  console.log("Window Height: ", height, "CSS Height: ", bodyTargetHeight);

  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (height < bodyTargetHeight) {
      popup.resizeTo(bodyTargetWidth, height += 5);
      if (height >= bodyTargetHeight) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      } else if (height > bodyTargetHeight) {
        popup.resizeTo(bodyTargetWidth, height -= 5);
        if (height <= bodyTargetHeight) {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
      } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 0);
  }, 0400);
}
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to make this more responsive, and smooth and eliminate all the twitching and clunkiness?

I guess the issue might be that I am increasing/diminishing by 5 pixels at a time but that is the speed I need. Maybe there is another way to increase/decrease by 1px at a faster rate? Could this be the cause of the twitching and clunkiness?

Also, I should add that troubleshooting this is difficult because the browser keeps crashing so there is also a performance issue sometimes when trying different things.

**EDIT:**

Another option using `resizeBy`:

```
function animateClose(time) {
  setTimeout(function () {
  var strW = getComputedStyle(window.document.querySelector(".body_zero")).getPropertyValue("width");
  var strW2 = strW.slice(0, -2);
  var strWdif = 32;
  var bodyTargetWidth = (parseFloat(strW2) + parseFloat(strWdif));
  var strH = getComputedStyle(window.document.querySelector(".body_zero")).getPropertyValue("height");
  var strH2 = strH.slice(0, -2);
  var strHdif = 54;
  var bodyTargetHeight = (parseFloat(parseInt(strH2)) + parseFloat(strHdif));

  var w = window.innerWidth; //Get window width
  var h = window.innerHeight; //Get window height

  var loops = time * 0.1; //Get nb of loops

  var widthPercentageMinus = (w / loops) * -0;
  var heightPercentageMinus = (h / loops) * -1;
  var widthPercentagePlus = (w / loops) * +0;
  var heightPercentagePlus = (h / loops) * +1;

  console.log("Window Height: ", h, "CSS Height: ", bodyTargetHeight);

  var loopInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if (h > bodyTargetHeight) {
      window.resizeBy(widthPercentageMinus, heightDecrheightPercentageMinuseasePercentageMinus);
    } else if (h < bodyTargetHeight) {
      window.resizeBy(widthPercentagePlus, heightPercentagePlus);
    } else {
      clearInterval(loopInterval);
    }
  }, 1);
}, 0400);
}
```

This one is a bit more smooth but I can't make it stop at the desired Height. It also is not differentiating between resizing up or down, also crashes the browser sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

maybe with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

try something like this (***not tested***):

```
function resizeWindow(popup) {
    var gcs = getComputedStyle(window.document.querySelector(".body_zero"));
    var strW = gcs.getPropertyValue("width");
    var strW2 = strW.slice(0, -2);
    var strWdif = 32;
    var bodyTargetWidth = (parseFloat(strW2) + parseFloat(strWdif));
    var strH = gcs.getPropertyValue("height");
    var strH2 = strH.slice(0, -2);
    var strHdif = 54;
    var bodyTargetHeight = (parseFloat(parseInt(strH2)) + parseFloat(strHdif));
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    console.log("Window Height: ", height, "CSS Height: ", bodyTargetHeight);
    
    window.myRequestAnimationFrame =    window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;
    var hStep = 2;      //choose the step. Must be an integer
    function internalFunc() {
        if (Math.abs(height - bodyTargetHeight) > hStep) {
            if (height < bodyTargetHeight)
                hStep *= 1;
            else if (height > bodyTargetHeight)
                hStep *= -1;
            popup.resizeBy(0, hStep);
            height += hStep;
            window.myRequestAnimationFrame(internalFunc)            
        } else
            popup.resizeBy(0, bodyTargetHeight - height)
    }
    popup.resizeTo(bodyTargetWidth, height);
    window.myRequestAnimationFrame(internalFunc)
}
```

Comment: Much better! But the speed is very slow. How to increase? Also I had to add ```setTimeout(function () {```  because without it the JS gets the CSS ```calc()``` for the properties too soon and the size gets wrong. I had to had a delay of ```}, 0400);``` which is acceptable. Now I just need for the transition to be faster. Not sure how to do it though.

Comment: getComputedStyle ***should*** returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, ***after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation*** those values may contain.
You could try to calculate the right value also in the JS though.
You will probably have to establish a balance between speed and smoothness.
Anyway, if you do not share with us a minimum complete and reproducible example, it is very difficult to understand where the problem lies.

Comment: It's just slow. Would be good to have a variable where speed could be manipulated. Let me try a JSFiddle so I can show you. One moment.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with JSFiddle or any other as the target URL via popup would have to be under my control for me to inject the transition code. I am in control of the target on the Extension because of the way it works. Or maybe there is a way but I do not know of it. So basically like I said the transition is just slow. I'll research how to increase speed or transition time for this. Thank you anyway for your reply I feel get close to a final solution.

Comment: If that window could become a fake window built as a set of divs, you could think of a CSS animation.

Comment: Thing is the point of this is to have the Chrome Extension to detach using ```window.open```` so I am forced to use window. Unless it is possible to use floating CSS windows as if they were sets of divs? Something like modals? But don't this sets of divs have to exist withing a window themselves?

Comment: Forget the idea of the window made with divs.
You should be sure to have an extension page under that window because if you have any web page then things would get complicated.

Comment: resizeBy could be more performante, give it a try. you can increment "height" by a not integer number i.e. 1.7 (but remember to trunc "height" before pass it to resize* method 'cause could thrown an error) Note the requestAnimationFrame is used to avoid redrawing of same pixels before the screen refresh (and also to avoid flickering)

Comment: I have added another option using ```resizeBy``` as suggested ( check my question on EDIT ) but I don't know how to use  ```requestAnimationFrame ``` there. This one is a bit more smooth than my 1st option but this one does not know when to stop. Also is not able to distinguish between when it should resize down or up.

Comment: I edited my answer. Your code (as it was written at the beginning) could run in an infinite loop being the offset\step different from one. If step is equal to one, sooner or later "height" reach the value of bodyTargetHeight. Now you can choose an arbitrary step value being sure that you will not run into an infinite loop.  "requestAnimationFrame" allows you to avoid the setInterval (you should read more about it).

Comment: As it is it does not resize. It just flickers and crashes the browser. The first version is better, just slow. I'm trying to find a fix for this.

Comment: I appreciate your effort BTW.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    const bodyTargetWidth = 150;
    const bodyTargetHeight = 250;   //target height
    var height;            //height at beginning

    window.myRequestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;

    var hStep = 5; //choose the step. Must be an integer
    var dir;
    
    var myPopup;
    
    function doResize() {
        function internalFunc() {
            console.log('height: ', height) ;
            if (Math.abs(height - bodyTargetHeight) > hStep) {
                dir = Math.sign(bodyTargetHeight - height);
                
                myPopup.resizeBy(0, dir * hStep);
                height += dir * hStep;
                
                window.myRequestAnimationFrame(internalFunc)
            } else
                myPopup.resizeBy(0, bodyTargetHeight - height)
        }
        if (!myPopup || myPopup?.closed)  {
            myPopup = window.open("about:blank", "hello", "left=200,top=200,menubar=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no");
            height = 150;
            myPopup.resizeTo(bodyTargetWidth, height);
        } else {
            myPopup.focus();
            height = myPopup.outerHeight
        }
        myPopup.resizeTo(bodyTargetWidth, height);
        window.myRequestAnimationFrame(internalFunc)
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', doResize))
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn">Create popup<br>\<br>Reset popup height</button><br>
    <p>First create the popup, then change popup height and click the button above again</p>
</body>
</html>
```